# Communication Speed, Tcp/Ip vs Serial

Tags: serial, hardware, tcp-ip

'm using a turnstile using TCP/IP Communication(RJ-45 cable) with my application.
And it's taking about 20minuts to finish some functions (Like: Selects in the database, and set some configuration of the own turnstile's dll.).

The same application, with the same database, but using a Serial Communication type(RS-232 port).
And it's taking 4minuts.

My doubt is:

The applications have just 2 or 3 different values in theier configurations, just to tell to my application wich one is tcp/ip or serial. Why this big different of performance?

**UPDATE**

Let me give a better explanation.
This turnstile is placed in the entrace of a CLUB. I need this turnstile to work offline, so  I need to export the information of the users, it makes a lot of checks to verify if the users are allowed or not to enter in the club. This exportation of information from my database(PC) to the turnstile's buffer is a little long. It takes 4minuts to finish using `Serial-RS232` communication, and 30minuts when using `TCP/IP`. I Need to know if it is normal or not.

Comment: What does "turnstile" mean in this context?

Comment: @DaveTweed  Like this image:
http://image.made-in-china.com/2f0j00ivFErMtDnobJ/Waist-Height-Turnstile.jpg

Sorry if I used to wrong word. Please, Correct me if I said it wrong. THanks for the reply.

Comment: No, that's the right word for that device, but now I'm completely confused about what a turnstile has to do with doing "selects in the database". Please tell us more about your application.

Comment: @DaveTweed assuming it's a id based turnstile. Uses RFID or mag stripe card to know who to let through or deny entry, which id to charge, etc. It's just a different style of electronic doorway.

Comment: @Passerby: In that case, the response time needs to be measured in milliseconds, not minutes. Even 4 *seconds* would be way too long for this sort of thing.

Comment: @DaveTweed I'm assuming based on OPs question, that the turnstile has an embedded computer with a local database, instead of a central network database it connects to on each swipe. Not efficient, but not unheard of either. Still way not enough info to properly help OP.

Comment: @Passerby Sorry about that... Let me give a better explanation.  
This turnstile is placed in the entrace of a CLUB. I need this turnstile to work offline, so  I need to export the information of the users, it makes a lot of checks to verify if the users are allowed or not to enter in the club. This exportation of information from my database(PC) to the turnstile's buffer is a little long. It takes 4minuts to finish using `Serial-RS232` communication, and 30minuts when using `TCP/IP`. I Need to know if it is normal or not.

Comment: TCP/IP is a different layer than "serial" - TCP/IP communications can happen over serial links.

Comment: @JohnU - that's not helpful in the least.  While in theory such systems exist, even from the *original* version of this question it could be easily deduced that for this device RS232 serial vs TCP/IP over Ethernet are two *distinct* options.

Comment: Given the helpfulness and coherence of the OP, I didn't think it was dragging the tone down overall... Only trying to encourage a little clarity and possibly even pausing for thought.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro the two things to do is check the connection speed of the ethernet connection, it might be connecting at base 10 or base 1 speeds. And check for packet loss (ping the turnstile's ip address).

Answer (score 3):

While ethernet is faster than a typical RS-232 interface for moving large amounts of data, it can actually be *slower* for rapidly interactive communication of short messages where the next item won't begin until the previous is finished.

Particularly if you are using TCP, one of the speed/sharing optimizations called the Nagle algorithm can end up slowing down brisk interchanges by inserting 200ms delays before the acknowledgement.  That limits certain types of exchanges to about 5 messages per second, which in a pathological case of a communication scheme poorly adapted to this quickly add up to large amounts of time.  Depending on the details of the systems, disabling may or may not be possible.

Another possibility is that you are setting up and tearing down the connection for each of a long list of operations.

Edit: it sounds like you are using a DLL provided by the device vendor to do the access, so you may not have awareness of what is actually going over the wire.  Setting up a packet sniffer on the machine which is talking to device would be a good idea - in particular, look at the time stamps of the packets and see if you can figure out where there are delays in the traffic, probably in an operation that is repeated hundreds of times.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro - your update doesn't really provide much beyond what could be guessed.  Sniff the packets and figure out what is actually going on.